# Can't connect to MySQL on tomcat but it is connecting as a standalone java class using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, web-applications

I have been trying to connect to my MySQL database using hibernate from my web based application on my windows system.
I have tried disabling the windows firewall, have bypassed the defender on port 3306,have tried writing the bind address as 127.0.0.1 to the my.inf file, have tried connecting using localhost and the ip 127.0.0.1
the MySQL server is up and running on the system.
I am able to connect to the db both via SQL workbench and Command Prompt (both using MySQL -u root -p and MySQL -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1)

my program connects to the db with the same hibernate configuration and jdbc configuration when it is run as a stand alone application ( just a test class in my web application ) .

the program throws and exception when it is run on tomcat server

I would appreciate any help.

the exception is as follows

```
    Root Cause
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
    com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:130)
    org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1387)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    com.octalian.oss.dao.impl.admin.user.UserDAOImpl.authorizeUser(UserDAOImpl.java:43)
    com.octalian.oss.service.impl.admin.user.UserServiceImpl.authorizeUser(UserServiceImpl.java:41)
    com.octalian.oss.controller.user.LoginController.authorizeUser(LoginController.java:85)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:892)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1537)
    ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:96)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:88)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1613)
    ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:467)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:431)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:351)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:403)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:349)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:422)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:284)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:260)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:69)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:188)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:120)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:244)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:155)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:130)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:556)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:113)


Root Cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:130)
    org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1387)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    com.octalian.oss.dao.impl.admin.user.UserDAOImpl.authorizeUser(UserDAOImpl.java:43)
    com.octalian.oss.service.impl.admin.user.UserServiceImpl.authorizeUser(UserServiceImpl.java:41)
    com.octalian.oss.controller.user.LoginController.authorizeUser(LoginController.java:85)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:892)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1537)
    ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:96)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:88)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1613)
    ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:467)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:431)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:351)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:403)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:349)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:422)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:284)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:260)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:69)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:188)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:120)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:244)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:155)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:130)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:556)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:113)
```

please note the pictures as well

[java main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE6g8.png)

[hibernate config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSe8u.png)

[ping to 127.0.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFrHK.png)

[MySQL workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VJtu.png)

[windows defender, I have tried 3306 as enabled and disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBB7W.png)

the anti virus is off

Thanks a ton for your help

Comment: Please share your jdbc connection properties...

Comment: hi the configuration details are in the link "hibernate config" it is a screenshot

Comment: Try to add useSSL=false parameter to your connection url..

Comment: Still no luck ...

Comment: After adding the useSSL are you getting the same error? sample url should be as 'mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DBNAME?useSSL=false'

Comment: yep , I am doing this jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/oss_dev?useSSL=false&amp;autoReconnect=true;

Comment: As per the details you have shared issue seems for useSSL...try to remove autoReconnect parameter and also good if you can share the mySql and java version you are using...

Comment: MySQL version 8.0.13 
java verion 1.8

Comment: also i removed the autoReconnect : it showed the same error

Comment: Try to disable the ssl connection to your mysql. You can see at  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199154/mysql-workbench-failed-to-connect-at-localhost3306-with-user-root-ssl-connectio

Comment: yes tried that as well, the workbench is connecting to the server properly. it is the web application that is not connecting.

Comment: what is the version of your mysql-connector jar?

Comment: it is mysql connector 8.0.13

Comment: please cross check your connector version and update it accordingly.have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html

Comment: yes I have been using the correct versions

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid in admitting this, my program had an a static block and a spring configuration trying to connect to the database and was causing the issue. The issue was solved by removing the static block and updating the spring configuration.

It was an architectural mistake.

Sorry for the trouble.

Thank you